# IntelliJ IDEA not stopping Tomcat server

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

I am running my Tomcat on my IntelliJ IDE. Whenever I stop my server, via the IDE, it never stops the server. Instead, I have to go manually kill it via the following command in my terminal:

```
ps -ef | grep tomcat
kill -9 <id>
```

I am not sure what is causing this issue. Is it safe to kill it every time?

Comment: Can you stop Tomcat with the shutdown script if you start it outside of IntelliJ IDEA with the same app deployed? It could be a bug in your app, if it creates threads and doesn't properly terminate these threads, Tomcat will not be able to stop with the shutdown script and will have to be killed.

Comment: Yep, you're right. I tried stopping it outside of IntelliJ via command terminal and it doesn't start. Looks to be an application issue. Going to be tough diagnosing the root cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA just calls the standard Tomcat shutdown script. If it can't stop the server, the issue is most likely with the application you have deployed. If the app creates threads and doesn't properly terminate them on the server shutdown, Tomcat will not be able to stop gracefully. You can use `jstack` to see which threads are running and preventing the server shutdown.